# getting curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number every time I run brew

Tags: curl, homebrew

Title. I've been unable to run brew due to this error. I'm not currently running any proxies or any other things that would disrupt online connection. When I run it in verbose, it prints this.

```
/usr/bin/curl --disable --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/3.0.2\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 11.2.1\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --location --range 0-1 --dump-header - --write-out \%\{http_code\} --output /dev/null https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/xorgproto-2021.3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/bin/curl --disable --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/3.0.2\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 11.2.1\)\ curl/7.64.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --retry 3 --location --remote-time --continue-at 0 --output /Users/cameron/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/4a01df4ef68ab52d11137a08c3675ac23d552925e4e667998e6d88ce18918d5d--xorgproto-2021.3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz.incomplete https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/xorgproto-2021.3.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number
```

Comment: Running into the same issue. I was attempting to install llvm and as got the following error: ==> Downloading homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libffi-3.3_2.big_sur.bottle curl: (35) error:1400410B:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_SRVR_HELLO:wrong version number. I tried switching networks just to make sure that wasn't the issue and I get the same error.

Comment: If my reply helped you, please, be sure to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you are just using curl for a post request, check that you are not using https instead of http.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31401560)

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with their CDN.

See here: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10739

A workaround would be adding this to your hosts file:

```
54.188.157.32 homebrew.bintray.com
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is currently a misconfiguration of the server or it is the wrong server to use. The server is not able to do any TLS handshake on port 443, no matter which client is used. From [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=homebrew.bintray.com):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have permissions to modify your `hosts` file, you can also try [this workaround](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10739#issuecomment-787484974):

```bash
~> HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN=https://dl.bintray.com/homebrew brew upgrade
```

to run the `brew upgrade` command while setting the `HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN` environment variable temporarily. It has solved my problem when upgrading my Brew packages.